# How to update bound data in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to update a network graph dynamically in D3.js.
Now my code is:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();
var my_nodes = [{"cluster": 0, "x": 50,  "y": 50},
                {"cluster": 0, "x": 100, "y": 50},
                {"cluster": 1, "x": 100, "y":100}];
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500);
var nodes = vis.selectAll("circle.node").data(my_nodes).enter().append("g")
               .attr("class", "node");
var circles = nodes.append("svg:circle")
                   .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                   .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
                   .attr("r", 5)
                   .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d.cluster)});
```

This code works.
But when I update data like:

```
var new_nodes = [{"cluster": 0, "x": 50,  "y": 50},
                 {"cluster": 2, "x": 100, "y": 50},
                 {"cluster": 2, "x": 100, "y":100}];
nodes.data(new_nodes);
```

doesn't work.

How can I update bound data?

EDIT: What I want to do is replacing old data `my_nodes` with new data `new_nodes`. Is there any way to update the attribute `cluster` of each bound data?

EDIT2: Suppose I do:

`d3.select("body").select("svg").selectAll("circle").data(mydata).enter().append("svg:circle");`

Can I modify `mydata`?

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no data-binding magic à la angular that's going to trigger a "redraw".  Just call `.data` and then re-set the attributes:

```
function update(){
 nodes
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.cluster)
  });
}

var nodes = vis.selectAll("circle.node").data(my_nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .append("svg:circle");
update();

// some time later

nodes.data(new_nodes);
update();
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ex4bWmy7t7m4eERzH1Lz?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you. One of problems was "redraw" problem that you pointed out, and the other problem was that "child nodes inherit parent data. But if parent data is updated, child data aren't updated automatically." So what I want to do is: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ixWDtnbl1iDSi71nTiNv?p=preview)

Answer (score 9):

Not sure how you'd want this to look, but I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/8ua144p4/4/

Clicking the `update` button will update to the new data.

I've based the changes off the [General Update Patterns](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) and [this article from Mike on Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)

I've put a transition on the `fill` attribute for each circle, so you can hopefully see that the nodes are being updated in this case rather than new nodes being added. I've also shown a 4th new node being added, to demo the difference.

Finally, I've simplified things a little by removing the `node` (`g`) elements and just using `circle`. This is the important code:

```
// DATA JOIN
// Join new data with old elements, if any.
var circle = vis.selectAll("circle").data(data);

// ENTER
// Create new elements as needed.
circle.enter().append("svg:circle").attr("r", 5);

// UPDATE
// Update old elements as needed.
circle.attr("cx", function (d) {return d.x;})
    .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;})
    .transition().duration(750)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.cluster)
});
// EXIT
// Remove old elements as needed.
circle.exit().remove();
```

When the data is updated, `force.start();` is run everytime so it looks like new data. If you remove that, it's easier to see what's happening but you lose the animation. What you probably want is to only animate entry for the new nodes (and maybe exiting nodes), but that would be a separate question

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What I wanted to do is replacing old data `my_nodes` with new data `new_nodes`. Sorry for my lack of explanation.

I am looking for how to update bounded data without `exit()` and `remove()`, for example in my case I want to update the attribute `__data__.cluster`, but according to your answer, there seems to no method to do that. Thank you.